# Python - EOFError with sockets

Tags: python, sockets

While learning sockets in Python I bumped into a problem, here's the code:

server.py

```
import socket
from threading import Thread
import time

def client_thread(c):
    while True:
        data = c.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            break
        print('Data received from client: ' + data.decode('utf-8'))

        time.sleep(1)
        c.send('Thank you!'.encode('utf-8'))
        break

    c.close()
    print('CONNECTION ENDED')
    time.sleep(1)

host = socket.gethostname()
port = 5000

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

s.bind((host, port))

print('Waiting for connection...')
s.listen(5)

while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print('Connected to: ' + str(addr))

    Thread(target=client_thread, args=(c,)).start()

s.close()
```

client.py

```
import socket
import time

host = socket.gethostname()
port = 5000

time.sleep(2)
c = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

c.connect((host, port))
print('Connected!')

time.sleep(1)

msg = input('Send data to server: ')
c.send(msg.encode('utf-8'))

while True:
    data = c.recv(1024)
    if not data:
        break
    print('Data received from server: ' + data.decode('utf-8'))

c.close()
```

I'm not sure how to run two clients at once so I tried this in the terminal (please correct me if it is not the right way):

```
 $ python server.py & python client.py & python client.py
```

Then I get the error:

```
Waiting for connection...
Connected to: ('127.0.0.1', 43952)                          
Connected!                                 
Connected to: ('127.0.0.1', 43953)                          
Connected!                            
Send data to server: Send data to server: Traceback (most recent call last):                                              
 File "client.py", line 16, in <module>                     
  msg = input('Send data to server: ')                    
EOFError: EOF when reading a line                          
CONNECTION ENDED
```

I think there is a problem with running two input() at once

How can I run multiple clients at once on the same device?

Comment: You can run multiple terminals and run client from them.

Comment: @FarbodShahinfar and how do you do that?

Comment: If you're on macOS, or a desktop linux system with a GUI, your terminal should be able to open as many windows as you want—but how to do that (a) is a question for Super User, not Stack Overflow, and (b) can't be answered without knowing what platform/distro/terminal/etc. you're using.

Comment: @abarnert I'm actually using a terminal emulator on Android and I'm not so sure it could do that. The android IDE I'm using is Pydroid3 as I do not have my comp with me now

Comment: I have no idea if your Android terminal editor can do it, but you could search/ask for help on that on… whatever the appropriate SE site is for Android power users. Or you could always use `screen` or `tmux` to run multiple independent shell sessions inside a single terminal, but I'm guessing that's not going to be much fun with a phone keyboard…